# How to turn .text into an integer in selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

So the code I have right now is this:

```
    Products = (driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="products"]'))
    Product_price = Products.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[class='product unlocked enabled'] div[class='content'] span[class='price']")
    Product_names = Products.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[class='product unlocked enabled']")
    for items in range (len(Product_price)):
        Prices[(Product_names[items].get_attribute("id"))] = Product_price[items].text
```

I have a dict called Prices that collects the name and attaches that name to a value
My code only detcts the value (which is a number) when it is a str
so for example
when I have

> for items in range (len(Product_price)):
> Prices[(Product_names[items].get_attribute("id"))] = Product_price[items].text

It works.
but when I put int(Product_price[items].text) it stops working, and it no longer detects the
items im trying to get...what do I do here?

Comment: I have tried looping through the dict and making each value an int, but that doesn't work either I have tried creating another dict and putting all the values from my Prices to the other dict, and that doesn't work either

Comment: Putting `int()` around `Product_price[items].text` can't make it "stop working".  Show us the actual code you tried, and the result.

Comment: Does `Product_price[items].text` contains only digits or letters too?